# Ошибка при установке SASS в OS Windows

Tags: windows, sass, install

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.125]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation), 2017. Все права защищены.

C:\Users\vladi>gem install sass  
Fetching: rb-fsevent-0.10.2.gem (100%)  
Successfully installed rb-fsevent-0.10.2  
Fetching: ffi-1.9.18-x64-mingw32.gem (100%)  

ERROR:  Error installing sass:
        The last version of ffi (< 2, >= 0.5.0) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 1.9.18. Try installing it with `gem install ffi -v 1.9.18` and then running the current command again
        ffi requires Ruby version < 2.5, >= 2.0. The current ruby version is 2.5.0.
```

При установке SASS выдает данную ошибку, ожидаю помощи.

Comment: Даже не разбираясь, сразу бросается в глаза что версии разные.

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь установлена последняя версия Ruby. Что нужно мне сделать в данной ситуации ? Сам новичок.

Comment: Ошибаешься. Сам же и запостил `The current ruby version is 2.5.0`. https://rubyinstaller.org/ это подтверждает.

Comment: @donRumata так наоборот, он **не** ошибается. Последняя версия [действительно 2.5.0](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/), она у него и установлена.

Comment: @D-side, аа, ну я снова не умею читать. Блин. В который раз :(

Answer (score 1):

## На данный момент

...единственный **простой** выход для вас — установить более **старый** Ruby, например 2.4.3.

RubyGems выбрал самую новую версию гема `ffi`, который поддерживает, как и сказано:

```
ffi requires Ruby version < 2.5, >= 2.0. The current ruby version is 2.5.0.
```

Версия `2.5.0` не удовлетворяет требованию `< 2.5`.

Проблема [известна](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/598) и даже неделю назад [исправлена](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/pull/599), поэтому, как вариант, можно дождаться очередного релиза `ffi`. Или, если вас тянет на приключения, можно установить гем прямо [из репозитория](https://github.com/ffi/ffi) с помощью указания его в `Gemfile` или сборки-установки вручную.

[На сайте RubyInstaller](https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/), кстати, об подобных проблемах предупреждают:

> **Don’t use the Ruby 2.5.0 installer**, unless you want to solve issues when installing gems! If you don’t know what version to install and you’re getting started with Ruby, we recommend you use Ruby 2.4.X as x64 or x86 installer. These provide a stable language and the biggest number of compatible gems.

> **Не используйте установщик Ruby 2.5.0**, если не хотите решать проблемы с установкой гемов! Есливы не знаете, какую версию ставить, и только осваиваете Ruby, мы рекомендуем использовать Ruby 2.4.X из установщика под x86 или x64. Вы получите стабильный язык и наибольшее количество совместимых гемов.

Comment: То что вы мне порекомендовали установить с репозитория, то это я никогда не сделаю. Придется ожидать нового релиза ((

Comment: @ВладиславЧерепня а установить более старый Ruby, например из линейки 2.4 (на RubyInstaller есть 2.4.3), для вас не вариант?

Comment: @ВладиславЧерепня обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую.

Comment: Ура XD, SASS установился, большое вам спасибо. Вопрос можно закрывать.

Comment: @ВладиславЧерепня не, у нас закрытие только для неуместных на SO вопросов, а этот очень даже к месту. Ознакомьтесь с [туром](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour). Вопрос считается решённым, когда на каком-нибудь ответе в нём стоит галочка.